# Method Not Allowed (POST) - search

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter, django-tables2

The quest: add simple search on top of a django-table to filter it's values.

Problem: f^tup somewhere and getting this error when passing request after putting value in search window:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /warscrolls/
[22/Jun/2018 10:27:17] "POST /warscrolls/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

My url is like this:

```
url(r'^warscrolls/$', ScrollListView.as_view(filter_class=ScrollListFilter,
        template_name='scroll_list.html'), name='warscrolls'),
```

My search form in html template looks like this:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline form-search pull-right">
{% csrf_token %}
<div>
<input id="search_form_id" name="search" type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" placeholder="ID, Name, Account #, ZIP"{% if search %} value="{{ search }}"{% endif %}>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable `POST` request your class based view should implement `post()` method. But django `ListView` class does not implemented `post()` method by default and this raise the error.

Actually it's common practice to use `GET` request for search option, so to fix error you can simple update your html form like this:

```
<form method="get" class="form-inline form-search pull-right">
<div>
<input id="search_form_id" name="search" type="text" class="form-control col-md-3" placeholder="ID, Name, Account #, ZIP"{% if search %} value="{{ search }}"{% endif %}>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: That was easy. Thank you.